# Understanding what exactly is the NodeMCU

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

So the NodeMCU looks like this:

[image]

And the ESP12 is this:
[image]

So I can see that the little ESP12 is riding on the NodeMCU.

my question is: What is included in the ESP12 and what in the NodeMCU, in context of processor, RAM, flash, firmware, etc.? Just trying to understand the individual components of it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHocU-VqsF0 -- 8 min watch.

Comment: NodeMCU is the name of the LUA firmware.and the board is a NodeMCU development board meaning development board for NodeMCU. but the boards got more popular then the firmware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESP-12 contains the esp8266 MCU, flash memory, antenna and required external components.

The NodeMCU dev board is a breakout board that contains the ESP-12 module, the required boot pin configuration and provides connectors and circuitry to supply the ESP module with power and allow programming via USB including the auto-reset circuit, and otherwise access the pins and features of the ESP and in a form factor that can be easily used by hobbyists such as plugging it onto a breadboard.

Answer (score 1):

The product name is printed on it, and you can put it into Google: https://www.espressif.com/en/products/socs/esp8266

[Other places will give a handy summary.](https://components101.com/development-boards/nodemcu-esp8266-pinout-features-and-datasheet)

> Microcontroller: Tensilica 32-bit RISC CPU Xtensa LX106
>
> Flash Memory: 4 MB
>
> SRAM: 64 KB
>
> Clock Speed: 80 MHz

The other components on the carrier board are

> USB-TTL based on CP2102 is included onboard

The esp8266 doesn't speak USB natively, so the second chip is there to convert.

The three-pins-and-tab component bottom right will be a voltage regulator.

Comment: citing the link you provided: "NodeMCU is an open-source Lua based firmware and development board". So the firmware (which I suppose is on the Flash) is said to be of the "NodeMCU", which as far as I understand is the thing holding the ESP12 so.. I'm confused